# Print out bitset quickly in c++

Tags: c++, performance, binary, output, bitset

Im writing a program that outputs binary, and I got alot of it I want to output to the terminal, but this takes along time.
In other places in my program where I want to quickly output strings I use

```
_putchar_nolock
```

and for floating point and decimal numbers I use

```
printf
```

Currently my code looks like this for outputting binary numbers

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
{
    std::cout << (std::bitset<8>(binarynumbers[i]));
}
```

the output gives a nice 0s and 1s which is what I want, no hex. Issue is when I ran performance benchmarks and testing, I found that std::cout was significantly slower than _putchar_nolock and printf.

Looking online I could not find a way to use printf on a bitset and have it output 0s and 1s. and _putchar_nolock would seem like it would be just as slow having to do all the data conversion.

Does anyone know a fast and efficient way to output a bitset in c++?
My program is singlethreaded and simple so I dont have an issue putting unsafe code for performance in there, performance is a big issue in the code right now.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know how to convert a numeric value to binary? Why waste time converting something to a `std::bitset` just to print it out? Simply do this yourself and produce the output by completing bypassing the well-known overhead of iostream and using your operating system-specific system calls to `write()` the binary representation to the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `cin` and `cout` try to synchronize themselves with the library's stdio buffers. That's why they are generally slow;
you can turn this synchronization off and this will make `cout` generally much faster.

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);//use this line
```

You can also get an `std::string` from the bitset using the `to_string()` function. You can then use `printf` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to drop comment don't have enough reps. You can use [to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string) member of bitset class. This probably should work:

```cpp
std::cout << std::bitset<8>(binarynumbers[i]).to_string();
```